# Numpy array and how to assign values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Working with 3D array. In nested for loop using if condition to assign all values in 3D array equal to one given value.

```
import numpy as np 
Topvalue = 1000
center = 5
dim = 2
Bgr = 4
err = 0
#
x = np.ones(dim)
y = np.ones(dim)
z = np.ones(dim)
A =np.array(np.ones((dim,dim,dim)))*Bgr

Rin=[9.89/2]
Rout=[11.89/2]

for i in range (len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            print(A[i][j][k]=0)
            value = (np.sqrt(np.power(((i-center)/2),2) + np.power(((j-center)/2),2) + np.power(((k-center)/2),2)))
            if value >(Rin[0]-err):
                A[i][j][k] == Topvalue #np.where(A = np.ones((dim,dim,dim))*Bgr, Topvalue, A)    
                if value >=(Rin[0]-err) and (value<Rout[0]):
                    A[i][j][k]==0
                    print(A[i][j][k])
```

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: Which line?  `print(A[i][j][k]=0)` looks wrong

Comment: Comment out `print(A[i][j][k]=0)`

Comment: Now script runs.  has removed print(A[i][j][k]=0 but does not show any output.. why?

Comment: Which line(s)? has/have the syntax error?

Comment: @wwii if you see in code. is it right position to print out output in loop efter if condition. it seems code runs but does not show any output. But when i print outside loop it shows predefined values of array A. any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you asking for help with `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`? Or are you asking generally why your code doesn't do what you want? If statements in an `if` statement's suite aren't executing then the condition in the `if` statement must be False. [The if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.